# Cannot compile F() macro with R"string"

Tags: esp8266, c++, c, string

I am trying to compile the following code:

```
logger.log_info(F(R"(some text here that may take
    multiple lines
    and here it is done.)"));
```

But the compiler exists with the following error:

> error: unterminated raw string

I am able to use either `R` or `F`, but not both together. **How should I be able to use them together?**

Comment: Have you tried terminating the string manually, by adding `\0` to the end? Maybe that helps, as the error message complains about the string not being terminated

Comment: @chrisl because I am using `R`, how should `\0` be evaluated as string termination?

Comment: @chrisl, I tried it, but I am not able to compile because the whole remaining file is now evaluated as part of the string. So this did not work.

Comment: There were some bugs with raw string literals and the preprocessor in GCC a while back. What version are you using?

Comment: @Mat, Arduino libraries 2.7.4; GCC: 7.3.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put:

```
    #define DO_NOTHING(s) (s)

    DO_NOTHING(R"xyz(Hello
    World)xyz")
```

you can see g++ choke on preprocessing the raw string literal in the macro invocation with the latest esp8266 board package as of writing (version 2.7.4).  This comes with g++ 4.8.2 for xtensa.

```
    ~/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-4-b40a506/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++ -E  donothing.h
```

You may need to adjust the command-line for your system.  donothing.h is just the macro and invocation described above.

Result:

```
# 1 "donothing.h"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "donothing.h"


donothing.h:3:13: warning: missing terminating " character [enabled by default]
 DO_NOTHING(R"xyz(Hello
             ^
(R"xyz(Hello World)
donothing.h:4:10: warning: missing terminating " character [enabled by default]
 World)xyz")
          ^
      xyz")
```

This does not happen with g++ 9.3.0 on an amd64 Linux target.

As a workaround you can reconstruct (more or less) what the F() macro does with the following:

```
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);
    }

    void loop() {
      static const char pgm_str[] PROGMEM = (R"xyz(Hello
    World)xyz");

      Serial.println(FPSTR(pgm_str));
      delay(4000);
    }
```

Comment: May I ask you why would you write something outside of the parenthesis of the literal? (namely *xyz* in your example)? If this is not gonna be shown anyway

Comment: Do you have any suggestion to convert the output of the `FPSTR(pgm_str)` to std::string? because the is the type of the argument I am using. This is the error I get now: `no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const __FlashStringHelper*' to 'const string& {aka const std::basic_string<char>&}`

Comment: std::string works by allocating from dynamic memory, except maybe for small strings, so in order to wind up with one you'd need to copy into it.  In other words, at some point you'll have a second copy in RAM.  What are you ultimately doing with the string?  BTW: the arduino String class usually accepts const __FlashStringHelper *, but this inn't what your ultimately want and it would be a little nuts to load it into one and then the other.

Comment: You are right, thanks for that point. That means, using `const char *` instead of `String or std::string` should be fine in this case, as no copying will happen and I will be fine to use this string for logging. Right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Where does logger.log_info come from?  Is this a published library you can point me to?  I ask, because if it was made with the Arduino in mind, it is likely that there is some support in it already for reading strings out of "PROGMEM".

Comment: No, actually it is not, it is written somewhen by myself, logging data are simply some strings that will be built in runtime. For example: `logger.log_info("Current time " + time);`. And the argument its takes is `std::string`, I can simply change it of course to `const char *`. However, now after changing the argument type, the compiler still complaining about the type: `error: no matching function for call to 'Logger::log_info(const __FlashStringHelper*) const'`.

Could you keep trying helping me please to solve this? I will accept anyway the answer cuz the main question has been solved!

Comment: Heh, unfortunately this is a horrible medium to try to hold a conversation on.  There's probably some policy against suggesting this, but you can find me on irc.freenode.net in #arduino      I can try to edit the answer to include a routine to load std::string from __FlashStringHelper if you like.  Or, I suppose it could just go into a comment, since it's not part of the actual answer to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116022/discussion-between-mohammed-noureldin-and-timemage).